# How to push one table values to another table by selecting one or more row using angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

[image]Hi I am currently having a requirement issue here, I am trying to display the two tables.

Table one data:

```
TableOne =[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "ONLINE",
    "Status": false,
    "Track": false,
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "ONLINE",
    "Status": false,
    "Track": true,
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "DEAL",
    "Status": true,
    "Track": false,

  },
  {
    "Id": 4,
    "Name": "OFFLINE",
    "Status": false,
    "Track": false,

  },

]
```

Table 2 data:

```
Tab =[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "ONLINE",
    "Status": false,
    "Track": false,
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "ONLINE",
    "Status": true,
    "Track": false,
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "DEAL",
    "Status": true,
    "Track": false,

  },
]
```

Table one

```
Id  Name    Status  Track
1   ONLINE      false
2   ONLINE      true
3   DEAL        false
4   OFFLINE     false
Table two

Id  Name    Status  Track
1   ONLINE      false
2   ONLINE      false
3   DEAL        false
```

Here is the issue that I am facing: **How do I get one of multiple table row(s) values by using checkbox selection? And by pressing a button how can I push table one's selected values to table two?**
Also

1. Selecting the rows from table one and pushing it to table two
2. Suppose if table one has the name: Online and table two has the name: Offline with same id number, will it then overwrite it?
3. Upon clicking the button how can I get the selected row(s) values on that button click?

Below is my stackblitz link.

https://angular-mf2re7.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited according to comment:

1

First of all we should create arrays that will store selected items from each table:

```
  readonly TableOneSelections = [];
  readonly TabSelections = [];
```

After user check/uncheck record we will call function that will add/remove record from selection list

```
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="onSelectionChanged($event, D, TableOne)"></td> //first table
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="onSelectionChanged($event, D, Tab)"></td> //second table
```

Function implementation:

```
  onSelectionChanged(event, record, table) {
    const selections = table === this.TableOne ? this.TableOneSelections : this.TabSelections;
    event.target.checked
      ? selections.push(record)
      : selections.splice(selections.findIndex(selection => selection.Id === record.Id), 1)
  }
```

Then we can create buttons that will be used to move selected records. Each button when clicked will call `moveSelectedRecords` function that will move selected records to another table.

```
<button (click)="moveSelectedRecords(TableOne, Tab)">Move down</button> //first table
<button (click)="moveSelectedRecords(Tab, TableOne)">Move up</button> //second table
```

Implementation of `moveSelectedRecords` function:

```
  moveSelectedRecords(fromTable: any[], toTable: any[]) {
    const selections = fromTable === this.TableOne ? this.TableOneSelections : this.TabSelections;
    selections.forEach(selectedRecord => {
      const removedRecordIndex = fromTable.findIndex(record => record === selectedRecord);
      const removedRecord = fromTable.splice(removedRecordIndex, 1)[0];
      toTable.push(removedRecord);
    });
    selections.length = 0;
  }
```

2

Using function mentioned in (1) records with same `Id` will not be overwritten. If we want to do it we can use slightly modified function:

```
  moveAndOverwriteSelectedRecords(fromTable: any[], toTable: any[]) {
    const selections = fromTable === this.TableOne ? this.TableOneSelections : this.TabSelections;
    selections.forEach(selectedRecord => {
      const removedRecordIndex = fromTable.findIndex(record => record === selectedRecord);
      const removedRecord = fromTable.splice(removedRecordIndex, 1)[0];
      const indexInSecondTable = toTable.findIndex(record => record.Id === removedRecord.Id);
      indexInSecondTable !== -1
        ? toTable[indexInSecondTable] = removedRecord
        : toTable.push(removedRecord)
    });
    selections.length = 0;
  }
```

3

You can create another buttons that will call function `getSelectedRecords` for specific table:

```
<button (click)="getSelectedRecords(TableOne)">Get selected records</button> //first table
<button (click)="getSelectedRecords(Tab)">Get selected records</button> // second table
```

Inside function you can use selection arrays

```
  getSelectedRecords(fromTable: any[]) {
    const selections = fromTable === this.TableOne ? this.TableOneSelections : this.TabSelections;
    console.log(selections)
  }
```

working app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d1smii

Comment: @Wihelm we should not modify the status property it is the part of dynamic data instead of that we can create a seperate check box property so that it can retrieve the selected / selected all records

Comment: I updated my answer, now selections are stored separately.

Comment: your previous logic was absolutely perfect but there was some enhancement needed 1. beside id column a seperate header will be placed lik select here we can use one record or more than one /select all   2. in your program your are taking**status** field data and doing the modification actually we wont take it. we take select header beside id column and from there by selecting all the  data will be selected

Comment: Please check my updated question and here when status is true in table one and when we push it to the table two then it should display true . like selected values

Comment: Not sure if I understand. You want table with columns [select, id, name, status, track] and select column should display checkboxes used to select record we want to move? So 'status' column should be the same like in your stackblitz link?

Comment: Yeah status column should display the default dynamic values if Tru means checked and false mean unchecked and can we check /uncheck the status column after pushing to table and before saving so that if we want want we can check the status for some fields

Comment: Check updated app, now it should work like you wanted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166122/discussion-between-techieboy-and-wilhelm-olejnik).

Comment: @Wilhem I am getting Duplicate Values in the table2 It is not overwriting